# AWSTextract text APIs for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, aws-sdk, amazon-textract

I want to use the `AWSTextract` to scan text from the given Document and get the scanned text. So I Started working on the `AWSTextract` Documentation. But in the documentaion, I didn't find any APIs or pod for iOS to scan the given document and to get the scanned data? how can I achieve that in iOS.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks there is no iOS SDK yet.

Comment: Yes, currently there is no SDK for iOS. I've posted a question on GitHub. And got the response.